# Extracting the first item of a NSCFConstantString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsstring

I have the following output to the console saying that this class is a __NSCFConstantString

```
NSLog(@"select category instance %@", [[SelectCategory instance] getCategoryText].class);
```

the output of that the string is: **bar|cafe|grocery_or_supermarket|liquor_store|night_club**

how do I extract just the first category? (The categories are separated by "**|**") In this case it would be "**bar**". I then need to store that in a variable.

thanks for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `__NSCFConstantString` is an `NSString`, you can use the [`componentsSeparatedByString:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) method:

```
NSString *all = [[SelectCategory instance] getCategoryText];
NSString *first = [[all componentsSeparatedByString:@"|"] objectAtIndex:0];
```